# How can I use react-select to custom render subtext below each dropdown item?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to figure out how I can utilize the custom components in react-select to render a dropdown that has items with subtext.

I've looked at each one of the components on: https://react-select.com/components and not sure which one would best fit my needs.

From looking at the list of components, I believe the `option` component is meant for something like that and would probably work but i'm not sure. Can someone validate my thought?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**React-select V2+ solution:**

You are absolutely right, using `Option` component will allow you to format each option in the `menuList` like the follow example:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "text 1",
    subLabel: "subtext 1",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    label: "text 2",
    subLabel: "subtext 2",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    label: "text 3",
    subLabel: "subtext 3",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    label: "text 4",
    subLabel: "subtext 4",
    value: "4"
  }
];

const Option = props => {
  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <div>{props.data.label}</div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{props.data.subLabel}</div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} components={{ Option }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/53jomww8yn).

**React-select V1 solution:**

Keeping the same structure as the V2 solution, you can achieve to display a custom option element by passing a render function using the props `optionRenderer` like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  renderOption = option => (
    <div>
      <label>{option.label}</label>
      <label style={{ display: "block", color: "gray", fontSize: 12 }}>
        {option.subLabel}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select options={options} optionRenderer={this.renderOption} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/v680x6x8w0).

Comment: is something like this possible with v1?

Comment: @jshah I have updated my answer to provide you a v1 solution