# Adding some text next to an option in react-select based on the value

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-select

[image]

I am working with react-select and need to add the text as in the image 'default category' based on some condition. Any way to achieve this?

My code:

```
renderCategories(categories) {
   const temp = [];
   categories.forEach((key) => {
        temp.push({label: key.name, value: key.id.toString()});
   });
   return temp;
}

<Field
 name="event_category"
 component={renderSelectField}
 placeholder="Select Event Category"
 options={this.renderCategories(categories)}
/>
```

where renderSelectField is the Select component of react-select, using redux-form and categories is an array of objects containing id and name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use react-select to custom render subtext below each dropdown item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757550/how-can-i-use-react-select-to-custom-render-subtext-below-each-dropdown-item)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by providing your own custom `Option` template to react-select. Works a little like:

```
const OptionLayout = props => {
  const { innerProps, innerRef } = props;
  return (
    <article ref={innerRef} {...innerProps} className={'custom-option'}>
      <h4>{props.data.artist}</h4>
      <div className={'sub'}>{props.data.title} </div>
    </article>
  );
};

<Select {...selectProps} components={{Option: OptionLayout}} />
```

That's not a match for your layout, but should give you what you need to create your own custom `Option` template.