# how to set helperText in react-select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) and [TextField Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/). 
Is there possibility to set `helperText` (small text below component) in `react-select` like it is made in `TextField`?

Thank You for help in advance.

P.S. I do not think my question is duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757550/how-can-i-use-react-select-to-custom-render-subtext-below-each-dropdown-item). The other post is about how to custom component which is a part of react-select, I want to add an option that react-select doesnt have.

Comment: Hi Laura, I do not think it is duplication. The other post is about how to custom component which is a part of react-select, I want to add an option that react-select doesnt have.

Comment: Found that `InputLabel` & `NativeSelect` does not work well. The `shrink={true}` on `InputLabel` helped for me for `NativeSelect`, final one is `<InputLabel shrink={true}>Select A Role</InputLabel>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean placeholder?
I think You can set this way:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select placeholder="Select..." options={options} />
)
```

But if you want the same look why do you use controls from different libraries. I think you can use FormHelperText with [Select from Material-Ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/). So you might as well this select instead of react-select.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="age-native-label-placeholder">
    Age
  </InputLabel>
  <NativeSelect
    value={this.state.age}
    onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
    input={<Input name="age" id="age-native-label-placeholder" />}
  >
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value={10}>Ten</option>
    <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
    <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
  </NativeSelect>
  <FormHelperText>Label + placeholder</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, Placeholder is inside the field, in TextField it is called label. The HelperText is a small text below TextField

Comment: Thank You for an answer, but it is still not what I want. Select from MUI does not have many things which has react-select like for instance autocomplete, shortly, Select from MUI is not what I want to use.

Comment: and your snipped shows an Error {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: I do not intended to run this snippet from here. I removed the run button. I'm sure the react-select has no Helper text. But this text is under your control. So you might as well render text in a div after the react-select and set the style with css. Or you can try to use the FormHelperText component from material-ui with react-select.

Comment: ahh I see the point now! I will try the FormHelperText option, thanks ;)

Comment: Spelling `placeholder`

Answer (score 14):

`TextField` is mainly a convenience wrapper around several lower-level components including `FormHelperText`.

Here is the Autocomplete demo in the Material-UI documentation using react-select: https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/#react-select

Here is a modified version of that demo using `FormHelperText`: https://codesandbox.io/s/rynvn8po5p

Here's the relevant snippet from that code:

```
          <Select
            classes={classes}
            styles={selectStyles}
            options={suggestions}
            components={components}
            value={this.state.single}
            onChange={this.handleChange("single")}
            placeholder="Search a country (start with a)"
            isClearable
          />
          <FormHelperText>Here's my helper text</FormHelperText>
```

The Material-UI demos for Select also show many examples of using `FormHelperText` without using `TextField`: https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/#simple-select

Here is the API documentation for `FormHelperText`: https://material-ui.com/api/form-helper-text/